# boto3 handle ClientError during s3 file upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

When making a boto3 upload request with invalid credentials I would like to use a custom format for displaying an error message. I am trying to accomplish this in the following way,

```
try: 
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='blah', aws_secret_access_key='blah', region_name='us-west-2')
    s3_client.upload_file('test', 'bucket', 'test')

except ClientError as e:  # handle aws s3 exceptions
     msg = e.response.get('Error', {}).get('Message', 'Unknown')
     code = e.response.get('Error', {}).get('Code', 'Unknown')
     print('Failed to copy to S3 bucket: {msg} ({code})'.format(msg=msg, code=code))
```

Running this I get a traceback that looks similar to this (only including the exceptions),

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 279, in upload_file
.
.
.
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
.
.
.
boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload test to bucket/test: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

My assumption is during the upload_file call the ClientError is raised while another request runs async in the background. Once the ClientError begins processing the S3UploadFileError is raised which results in the traceback above. Is there any way to ignore the S3UploadFileError as this is redundant and does not have the same attributes as the ClientError  for custom formatting.

Comment: you can catch `S3UploadFailedError ` and throw a generic error?

Comment: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1986 open issue regarding this problem

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
try: 
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='blah', aws_secret_access_key='blah', region_name='us-west-2')
    s3_client.upload_file('test', 'bucket', 'test')

except S3UploadFailedError as e:
     raise CustomException(msg ='unknown error', Code = 0;)

except ClientError as e:  # handle aws s3 exceptions
     msg = e.response.get('Error', {}).get('Message', 'Unknown')
     code = e.response.get('Error', {}).get('Code', 'Unknown')
     raise CustomException(msg = msg, Code = code;)
except:
     print('Failed to copy to S3 bucket: {msg} ({code})'.format(msg=msg, code=code))
```

Comment: I am not doing a lot of python these days, just thought of sharing my thoughts.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. The issue here is I can't extract the code or message from the S3UploadFailedError which could have different codes such as SignatureDoesNotMatch or InvalidAccessKeyId, with their own respective pre-formatted messages.

Comment: the point is, if you want to ignore that error, you can  override with a generic message such as `Unknown Error` , updated the answer

Comment: @hmobrienv you would have to something in `except S3UploadFailedError as exc:` such as  `if "SignatureDoesNotMatch" in exc.args[0]`